# Not able to call procedure in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to call procedure in oracle apex but I am facing problem in displaying the output of procedure while passing the parameter as emp_id to that procedure from oracle apex. Can anyone help me?

1. procedure that I have written in SQL developer tool.

   ```
   create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(EMP_ID1 IN Number)
   As

   RESULT TIMESHEET_EMPLOYEES%ROWTYPE;

   BEGIN

   SELECT * INTO RESULT.EMP_ID,RESULT.NAME,RESULT.LOCATION,RESULT.CITY,RESULT.COUNTRY,RESULT.EMPLOYMENT_TYPE,RESULT.EMAIL_ID,RESULT.PHONE_NUMBER,RESULT.CREATED_BY,RESULT.CREATED_ON,RESULT.UPDATED_ON,

         RESULT.UPDATED_BY,RESULT.DATE_OF_JOINING,RESULT.ROLE_ID,RESULT.SUPERVISOR_ID FROM TIMESHEET_EMPLOYEES

         WHERE EMP_ID=EMP_ID1;



         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP_ID:'||RESULT.EMP_ID||' '||'NAME:'||RESULT.NAME||' '||'LOCATION:'||RESULT.LOCATION||' '||'CITY:'||RESULT.CITY ||' '||'COUNTRY:'||RESULT.COUNTRY||' '||'EMPLOYMENT_TYPE:'||

         RESULT.EMPLOYMENT_TYPE||' '||'EMAIL_ID:'||RESULT.EMAIL_ID||' '||'PHONE_NUMBER:'||RESULT.PHONE_NUMBER||' '||'CREATED_BY:'||RESULT.CREATED_BY||' '||'CREATED_ON:'||RESULT.CREATED_ON||' '||'UPDATED_ON:'||

         RESULT.UPDATED_ON||' '||'UPDATED_BY:'||RESULT.UPDATED_BY||' '||'DATE_OF_JOINING:'||RESULT.DATE_OF_JOINING||' '||'ROLE_ID:'||RESULT.ROLE_ID||' '||'SUPERVISOR_ID:'||RESULT.SUPERVISOR_ID);

   EXCEPTION

   WHEN OTHERS THEN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLCODE'||' '||SQLCODE);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM'||' '||SQLERRM);

   END;
   ```
2. herein oracle apex in PLSQL code I am trying to call that procedure but I am not able to see any output.

   ```
   BEGIN
      TEST_PROC(:P1_EMPID); 
   END;
   ```

Can someone help me as I am new to APEX???

Answer (score 0):

Apex can't display result of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`.

Two simple options you might use:

- add another, `OUT` parameter(s) to your current procedure, or
- convert this procedure to a function which returns the result as a *concatenated string*

Both of them should *return* the result into an item on the page.

For example, if it were a procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(EMP_ID1 IN Number,
                                      par_result out varchar2
                                     )
is 
  -- ... your current code goes here; I presume it does what you wanted

  -- at the end, return the result as
  par_result := 'EMP_ID:'||RESULT.EMP_ID||' '||'NAME:'||RESULT.NAME || ... 
end;
```

Call it in a process as

```
TEST_PROC(:P1_EMPID, :P1_RESULT);
```

---

As of code you wrote: if you declared `result` as `%rowtype`, it is simpler to insert directly into it, not into every separate *piece* of it. For example:

```
  select *
  into result                    --> this
  from timesheet_employees
  where emp_id = emp_id1;
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I will try to implement in a way you have explained.